# How do I filter CoreData results based on a relationship

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a list of users, each with

Users.accounts--->Accounts.measurements--->measurement.account

I want to pull all measurements from the measurements "table" where measurement.account=a specific account, and where measurement.type (a property) is "wind speed" as an example.

So I:
Create a fetch request on measurements
I want to create a predicate that says type="wind speed" and account={NSAccount object}

How do I do this?

Measurement type is easy:

```
*predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"measuretype = 'air speed'];
```

Specifying the relationship, I don't know:

```
myAccountObject *myAccount=[accountFromId:@"6785"];
*accountpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"account = ???",myAccount];
```

Comment: Did you try creating a predicate? What was it? What did it do?

Comment: Added contend to above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a predicate, `%@` is a var arg substitution for an object value, so

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"account = %@",myAccount]
```

is probably what you are looking for. Even for a constant string this is preferable, because it avoids problems with embedded quotation marks or other special characters, which would
have to be quoted otherwise. So your combined predicate would be:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"measuretype = %@ AND account = %@",
        @"air speed", myAccount]
```

For more information, see ["Predicate Format String Syntax"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) in the
"Predicate Programming Guide".